# Is Irene actually delusional in "The Famine King"?

Tags: short-stories, darcie-little-badger

At the end of "The Famine King", we are given the impression that Irene is delusional and that everything that relates to the windigo is actually just imagined:

> “Where did that bruise come from?” Az pointed to my throat. A purplish streak marked the curve below my chin. I understood why she was concerned. It resembled a self-inflicted injury, the impression of a makeshift noose. But much like the face print Mr. Botello left on my childhood window, the bruise was evidence of monsters. Real monsters. During my psychotic thrall, while I imagined wendigo conspiracies, ancient ghosts wrapped a sheet around my neck. I must have faith in my little specks of proof, because the alternative is too terrible. Above all, I fear that my life is one endless hypnopompic nightmare.

However, she seems to believe that it's all real. And there's one thing that makes me suspect that she's not delusional - the opening.

The story opens with Irene having a sleep paralysis vision of her neighbor at her window:

> Face pressed against the glass, it said, “Hey, Irene. I have a secret for you. People rarely starve like they used to.” It sounded like a shrill parody of the neighbor, Mr. Botello.
>
> “Go away,” I thought. “Stop.” Though young, I was accustomed to hypnopompic nightmares projected on reality, hallucinated monsters and voices without mouths.
>
> The silhouette withdrew, leaving marks where its skin had touched, where its hot breath had fogged, and where its nails had pawed the cold glass. As it dissolved into the 2 a.m. shadows outside, it called, “The hunger is still here.”
>
> [...]
>
> Sometimes, I heard my tattooed window repeating “the hunger, the hunger, the hunger” behind its curtain shroud.

However, that same neighbor *did* at that time did commit murder suicide, killing his wife and children.

Also, these "hunger" delusions seem eerily similar to what she would later encounter after seeing the trailer for *The Famine King*.

Does this mean that she wasn't delusional after all, or is she too much of an unreliable narrator for us to tell?